# Is it true that for any $n\geq 1$, $(\ln(x))^n < x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I try to graph it on Desmos but it does not seem to be the case?

Comment: Yes, it is not true for all $x$ and $n$. What is the problem?

Comment: It does not hold for any $x $ and $n $. But for $x$ large enough it is true for any fixed $n $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is false.  Take the natural log of both sides:
$$ \ln{(\ln(x))^n)} < \ln x$$
Now you can take the n out of the exponent:
$$ n\ln{\ln(x)} < \ln x$$
Now let $y = \ln x$:
$$n \ln y < y$$
For any $y > 1$, you can choose an $n$ big enough that the statement is false.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\mathrm e<3$. Now take $x=\mathrm e^2$ and $n=4$. Then $(\ln x)^4=2^4=16$, while $x<3^2=9$.